# Log - Differentiation (with respect to) time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I need the steps and result of Log - Differentiation wrt "time" of the following equation: 
\begin{equation}
    \dot{D}(t) = \mu (D(t) - a - Ah(t)^{\gamma})
\end{equation}

Where: a, $\mu$, A are constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. The log-derivative is nothing but the derivative of the function over the function.

$$\frac{d\ln(\dot D(t))}{dt} = \frac{\mu(\dot D(t) - A \gamma h(t)^{\gamma-1}\dot h(t))}{\mu(D(t) - a - Ah(t)^{\gamma})} = \frac{\dot D(t) - A\gamma h(t)^{\gamma-1}\ \dot h(t)}{D(t) - a - Ah(t)^{\gamma}} $$

The steps are trivial, just remember that

$$\frac{d\ln(f)}{dx} = \frac{f'}{f}$$